# how to explicitelly add items to the overflow menu in the actionbar

Tags: android, menu, action

I was wondering if it is possible to put items directly in the overflow menu on the actionbar. I am using ActionbarSherlock for my app (if this is relevant). I have several menu items, for instance: Add, Delete, Sort, About app, etc. These are all items for my actionbar menu. I would like to leave only "Add" outside, and put the rest in the overflow menu. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html Read the part about "showAsAction" for your XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to put items directly in the overflow menu on the actionbar.

Yes, set the attribute [`showAsAction`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) to `"never"`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/item"
      android:title="@string/item"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: Actually, I just tried that and it does not work. It does not show the overflow menu. What can I do?

Comment: Does the device have a menu button?